# Application error after deploying on heroku

Tags: docker, heroku

I have dockerized a django project and it runs on my local mashine with $dcoker run ,i uploaded the project on heroku and run bellow commands :

```
$ heroku container:login
$ heroku container:push web
$ heroku container:release web
```

so when i opened the address https://docker-on-test.herokuapp.com/ on browser i got  the Application error and after heroku logs --tail i realized this is the error i have :

```
=== Fetching app code

=!= There were problems parsing your heroku.yml. We've detected the following issues:

 in body must be of type object: "null"
```

this is Dockerfile :

```
    RUN mkdir /code
    WORKDIR /code
    ADD . /code/
    RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    RUN pip3 install -r requiremenrs.txt 
    RUN python manage.py migrate
    CMD ["python3","manage.py", "runserver","0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    container_name: code
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

and heroku.yml :

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
run:
  web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Comment: (a) At a glance your `heroku.yml` looks fine. But it looks like it's for a _Ruby_ (Rails?) application and you appear to be using Python and Django. (b) Your `Dockerfile` has a bunch of extra indentation in it. Is that in the real file? It also contains a typo: your requirements file should be called `requirements.txt`. I'm not sure if your actual file has the correct name or not. Does this build locally? Though I don't think Heroku uses the `docker-compose.yml` file at all, so that probably isn't your problem.

Comment: (c) The error clearly references `heroku.yml` so that's where the error likely is, but as I said in my last comment it looks well-formed at a glance. What encoding does that file have?